# How to make all elements of all columns align by creating empty spaces so that it stays in the same pattern

Tags: r

I have a temporal dataset, however, it is incomplete so I can not reconstruct the series accurately. These are the data:

```
df<-data.frame(year=c(2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015),
sample1=c("D","D","DDD","D","U","UU","UUU","U","D","DDD"),
sample2=c("U","UU","D","D","DDD","D","U","UU","UUU","U"),
sample3=c("D","DDD","D","U","UU","UUU","U","D","DDD","D"),
sample4=c("D","D","UUU","U","D","DDD","D","U","U",NA),
sample5=c(NA,"UU","D","U","UU","UUU","U","D","U",NA))
```

I need it to end up like this:

```
df2<-data.frame(year=c(2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,
2015,2016,2017,2018),
sample1=c(NA,NA,"D","D","DDD","D","U","UU","UUU","U","D","DDD",NA,NA,NA),
sample2=c("U","UU","D","D","DDD","D","U","UU","UUU","U",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
sample3=c(NA,NA,NA,"D","DDD","D","U","UU","UUU","U","D","DDD","D",NA,NA),
sample4=c(NA,NA,"D","D",NA,NA,NA,NA,"UUU","U","D","DDD","D","U","U"),
sample5=c(NA,"UU","D",NA,NA,NA,"U","UU","UUU","U",NA,NA,"D","U",NA))
```

I need all the columns aligned in the same pattern, the best result was using DNA alignment functions, but these times to find the best alignment invert the elements, in my case can not occur this.
I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Don't post a before and after data frames!! Explain with words what it is you are trying to achieve and show what you have tried so far

Comment: Hey @YuriOliveiraFeitosa! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Thank you for posting your data and what you would like to achieve. As SO is not a code factory, the first question is: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Sotos before and after is often more useful than explanation with words but of course it's best to have both clear and concise.

Comment: @snoram Being useful is not the (main) point here. The point is for us to see some attempt and that they took the time to construct a good question before answering. We are not a AnswerQs-As-A-Service site

Comment: @YuriOliveiraFeitosa Could we assume that "UD" is a typo? And why sample5 is not in your result?

Comment: @Sotos Sorry if I wasn't clear. I think it's laudable to post a before and after data.frame in a reproducible format---in this respect op beats more than 90% of other questions competing for attention. However I do agree that it is not sufficient for a good question.

Comment: @snoram I get your point. I agree too (better than a lot of other Qs). What set me off was the before & after without any explanation/effort.

Answer (score 0):

dplyr's [add_row](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tibble/versions/1.4.2/topics/add_row) function makes this pretty easy, once the initial dataframe exists.

```
library(dplyr)

df<-data.frame(year=c(2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015),
sample1 = c("D","D","DDD","D","U","UU","UUU","U","D","DDD"),
sample2 = c("U","UD","D","D","DDD","D","U","UU","UUU","U"),
sample3 = c("D","DDD","D","U","UU","UUU","U","D","DDD","D"),
sample4 = c("D","D","UUU","U","D","DDD","D","U","U",NA),
sample5 = c(NA,"UU","D","U","UU","UUU","U","D","U",NA))
df2 <- df %>%
  add_row(year = 2016:2018)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data_frame(year=c(2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015),
               sample1=c("D","D","DDD","D","U","UU","UUU","U","D","DDD"),
               sample2=c("U","UD","D","D","DDD","D","U","UU","UUU","U"),
               sample3=c("D","DDD","D","U","UU","UUU","U","D","DDD","D"),
               sample4=c("D","D","UUU","U","D","DDD","D","U","U",NA),
               sample5=c(NA,"UU","D","U","UU","UUU","U","D","U",NA)) %>% 
  add_row(year = c(2004, 2005), .before = 1) %>% 
  add_row(year = c(2016:2018))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 6
    year sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5
   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
 1  2004 NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
 2  2005 NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
 3  2006 D       U       D       D       NA     
 4  2007 D       UD      DDD     D       UU     
 5  2008 DDD     D       D       UUU     D      
 6  2009 D       D       U       U       U      
 7  2010 U       DDD     UU      D       UU     
 8  2011 UU      D       UUU     DDD     UUU    
 9  2012 UUU     U       U       D       U      
10  2013 U       UU      D       U       D      
11  2014 D       UUU     DDD     U       U      
12  2015 DDD     U       D       NA      NA     
13  2016 NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
14  2017 NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
15  2018 NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

Comment: If I understand well the OP, you totally missed the point. Your dataset is not ALIGNED on same patterns. The question is much more complicated than just adding rows. See at df2!

Comment: Yeah, you're right, now that I look more closely at df2. That pattern is really not obvious, it should have been explained better.